# TeXstudio + MikTex: "Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe"

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, texstudio

I'm running Win10, MikTex 2.9, and TeXstudio.  I tried to update my packages yesterday, and I think the update was interrupted by the computer going to sleep. Although all of the packages appear to be up-to-date (and MikTex Console says "no updates"), it also appears to have corrupted something in my installation.  Any suggestions for repair other than full uninstall/reinstall of MikTeX?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

TeXstudio Messages:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "temp".tex

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "temp".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

I downloaded and installed the latest version of TeXstudio (2.12.22) and then got this error pop-up when I open TeXstudio and when I try to compile:
[image: Error dialog: pdflatex.exe - Entry Point Not Found]

**Added 5pm:**

Running both "pdflatex temp.tex" and "texify temp.tex" from the command line produced the same result:

```
C:\Temp>texify temp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
_
```

And it simply sits there running. I found a process named "Make a TeX .fmt file" in the Task Manager, and then tracked down this in the *miktex-makefmt.log* file:

```
2020-03-20 16:42:32,481-0500 INFO  miktex-makefmt - starting with command line: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=latex --no-dump latex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2020-03-20 16:42:32,491-0500 INFO  makefmt - found input file: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\latex.ini
2020-03-20 16:42:32,491-0500 INFO  makefmt - Creating the latex format file...
2020-03-20 16:42:32,511-0500 INFO  makefmt - Running miktex-pdftex.exe...
2020-03-20 16:42:32,511-0500 INFO  makefmt - running: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=latex --job-name=latex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex latex.ini
2020-03-20 16:45:10,847-0500 FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-pdftex.exe failed on latex.ini.
2020-03-20 16:45:10,847-0500 FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-pdftex.exe failed on latex.ini.
2020-03-20 16:45:10,847-0500 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Info: 
2020-03-20 16:45:10,847-0500 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Source: 
2020-03-20 16:45:10,847-0500 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Line: 0
```

**Added 6pm:**
After running

```
miktex-pdftex --initialize --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
```

I get:

```
("C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/dehyph\dehyph
t.tex"
German Traditional Hyphenation Patterns `dehypht' Version 3.2a <1999/03/03>
(Formerly known under the name `ghyph31' and `ghyphen'.)))
! I can't find file `dehypht-x-2018-03-31.tex'.
```

Comment: Try on a command line `initexmf --force --mklinks --admin`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Progress. The error dialog no longer appears.  However, the build command in TeXstudio seems to hang indefinitely.  When I stop it, I get the same error ("Command crashed: pdflatex").   Note: it complained about the "--admin" flag, I think because I have it installed as personal.  Removing it, the command took a few seconds and completed with no feedback (went back to command prompt).

Comment: compile a small document on the command line to get a better error message.

Comment: @ulrike The command line itself never printed an error message. See my edit above. It seemed to just run indefinitely. I welcome other ideas, otherwise, I'm just going to wipe it and start over.

Comment: What do you get with `initexmf --dump=pdflatex`?

Comment: Blinking cursor, never finishes

Comment: Try in some empty folder (!) `miktex-pdftex --initialize  --enable-etex pdflatex.ini` If it stops at some error hit x and enter and then show the log file.

Comment: See edit above. Looking though package files, I see dehyph-exptl/dehypht-x-2019-04-04.  And in MikTeX Console this was one of the packages that updated yesterday.  Should I try uninstalling and/or reinstalling it via MikTeX Console?

Comment: Try `initexmf --mklangs `. Perhaps this refreshes your language.dat.

Comment: That did it!  I was able to run the MWE on the command line, as well as a more complicated file in TeXstudio (after downloading more packages).  Thanks!

Comment: Do you think my premise was correct - that it got interrupted in the update process and corrupted a config file (language.dat perhaps)?

Comment: yes, at the end of the update miktex normally does this steps (mklinks, mklangs etc).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @UlrikeFischer, the solution was to run the following from the command line:

```
initexmf --force --mklinks
initexmf --mklangs
```

Notes:

- The first line may not have been necessary in my case.
- I installed MiKTeX as "personal" or "single user".  If it had been "for everyone" or "system-wide," then I would have needed to add `--admin` to the end of these commands. See  https://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html